# How to proper load async data

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, loaddata

I am quite new in Flutter and am wondering how to properly load async data in a Widget. This is my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../api/api_result.dart';
import '../../../common/application.dart';
import '../../../models/survey.dart';
import '../../common/list_material_ink_well.dart';
import '../../common/loading_widget.dart';
import '../../common/main_layout.dart';
import '../../common/status_bar.dart';
import '../../common/status_bar_icon.dart';
import 'survey_poll.dart';

class SurveysPollsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SurveysPollsWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SurveysPollsWidgetState();
}

class SurveysPollsWidgetState extends State<SurveysPollsWidget> {
  bool isEditMode = false;
  Map<String, bool> activity = <String, bool>{};

  Future<List<Survey>?> getSurveys(Application application) async {
    ApiResult<List<Survey>>? apiResult =
        await application.repositories?.survey.getSurveys();

    if (apiResult?.error != null) {
      await application.auth.logout();
    }

    if (apiResult?.value != null && application.caches != null) {
      application.caches?.survey.saveSurveys(apiResult!.value!);
    }

    return apiResult?.value;
  }

  Future<List<Survey>?> getSurveysFromCache(Application application) async {
    List<Survey>? result = await application.caches?.survey.getSurveys();

    return result;
  }

  final MaterialStateProperty<Icon?> thumbIcon =
      MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
        return const Icon(Icons.check);
      }
      return const Icon(Icons.close);
    },
  );

  Widget _drawItem(Survey survey) => isEditMode
      ? ListMaterialInkWell(
          survey.name,
          navItem: Switch(
            thumbIcon: thumbIcon,
            value: activity[survey.id] ?? false,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                activity[survey.id] = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      : ListMaterialInkWell(
          survey.name,
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SurveyPollWebViewWidget(survey: survey),
            ),
          ),
        );

  void toggleEditMode() => setState(() {
        isEditMode = !isEditMode;
      });

  Widget _draw(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Survey>?> cachedData) =>
      Material(
        child: MainLayout(
            title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.surveysAndPolls,
            iconLeft: isEditMode
                ? StatusBarIcon(
                    StatusBar.goBackIcon.icon, (context) => toggleEditMode())
                : StatusBar.goBackIcon,
            iconRight: !isEditMode
                ? StatusBarIcon(
                    Icons.edit_outlined, (context) => toggleEditMode())
                : null,
            showLoading: !cachedData.hasData,
            children: cachedData.hasData ? cachedData.data!.map(_drawItem).toList() : []),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Consumer<Application>(
      builder: (_, application, __) => () {
            if (application.repositories == null) {
              return const LoadingWidget();
            }

            return FutureBuilder<List<Survey>?>(
                    future: getSurveysFromCache(application),
                    builder: (context, cachedData) => cachedData
                                .connectionState !=
                            ConnectionState.done
                        ? Container()
                        : cachedData.data != null
                            ? _draw(
                                context, cachedData)
                            : FutureBuilder<List<Survey>?>(
                                future: getSurveys(application),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) => _draw(
                                    context, snapshot),
                              ));
          }());
}
```

the problem here is that every time the state changes, by toggling the editMode or the switches, the screen flashes black (default background), because the entire widget is re-rendered and for short amount of time when `getSurveysFromCache` is called, `Container()` is rendered, so black.

A dirty solution is to add a state for the surveys:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../api/api_result.dart';
import '../../../common/application.dart';
import '../../../models/survey.dart';
import '../../common/list_material_ink_well.dart';
import '../../common/loading_widget.dart';
import '../../common/main_layout.dart';
import '../../common/status_bar.dart';
import '../../common/status_bar_icon.dart';
import 'survey_poll.dart';

class SurveysPollsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SurveysPollsWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SurveysPollsWidgetState();
}

class SurveysPollsWidgetState extends State<SurveysPollsWidget> {
  bool isEditMode = false;
  Map<String, bool> activity = <String, bool>{};
  List<Survey>? surveys;

  Future<List<Survey>?> getSurveys(Application application) async {
    ApiResult<List<Survey>>? apiResult =
        await application.repositories?.survey.getSurveys();

    if (apiResult?.error != null) {
      await application.auth.logout();
    }

    if (apiResult?.value != null && application.caches != null) {
      application.caches?.survey.saveSurveys(apiResult!.value!);
    }

    if (apiResult?.value != null) {
      for (Survey element in apiResult!.value!) {
        activity[element.id] = element.isActive;
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      surveys = apiResult?.value;
    });

    return apiResult?.value;
  }

  Future<List<Survey>?> getSurveysFromCache(Application application) async {
    List<Survey>? result = await application.caches?.survey.getSurveys();

    setState(() {
      surveys = result;
    });

    return result;
  }

  final MaterialStateProperty<Icon?> thumbIcon =
      MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
        return const Icon(Icons.check);
      }
      return const Icon(Icons.close);
    },
  );

  Widget _drawItem(Survey survey) => isEditMode
      ? ListMaterialInkWell(
          survey.name,
          navItem: Switch(
            thumbIcon: thumbIcon,
            value: activity[survey.id] ?? false,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                activity[survey.id] = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      : ListMaterialInkWell(
          survey.name,
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SurveyPollWebViewWidget(survey: survey),
            ),
          ),
        );

  void toggleEditMode() => setState(() {
        isEditMode = !isEditMode;
      });

  Widget _draw(BuildContext context, List<Survey>? surveys, bool hasData) =>
      Material(
        child: MainLayout(
            title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.surveysAndPolls,
            iconLeft: isEditMode
                ? StatusBarIcon(
                    StatusBar.goBackIcon.icon, (context) => toggleEditMode())
                : StatusBar.goBackIcon,
            iconRight: !isEditMode
                ? StatusBarIcon(
                    Icons.edit_outlined, (context) => toggleEditMode())
                : null,
            showLoading: !hasData,
            children: hasData ? surveys!.map(_drawItem).toList() : []),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Consumer<Application>(
      builder: (_, application, __) => () {
            if (application.repositories == null) {
              return const LoadingWidget();
            }

            return surveys != null
                ? _draw(context, surveys, true)
                : FutureBuilder<List<Survey>?>(
                    future: getSurveysFromCache(application),
                    builder: (context, cachedData) => cachedData
                                .connectionState !=
                            ConnectionState.done
                        ? Container()
                        : cachedData.data != null
                            ? _draw(
                                context, cachedData.data, cachedData.hasData)
                            : FutureBuilder<List<Survey>?>(
                                future: getSurveys(application),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) => _draw(
                                    context, snapshot.data, cachedData.hasData),
                              ));
          }());
}
```

A clean solution would be to call `getSurveysFromCache` and `getSurveys` in the `initState`, but I need my `Application` instance object which is returned by the `Consumer<Application>`.

Some hint how to do it properly and clean?

Comment: Riverpod.  Built-in caching using any strategy you can dream up.

Comment: Don't realy understand how it can help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend using Riverpod over Provider. There are couple of articles out there about pros&cons:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/provider-vs-riverpod-comparing-state-managers-in-flutter/
- https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/11/flutter-comparing-getit-provider-and-riverpod.html
- [Why you should use Riverpod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73467886/why-you-should-use-riverpod)

---

With Provider you are basically limited by BuildContext, but as I can see, you are using just some function calls to load data, so:

1. I would extract those from the provider
2. Instead mixing **setState** with provider, use just the provider to store states
3. Instead **Consumer** use **Selector**
4. Split up the code and listen to particular state changes only (with **Selector**)
5. Init data with null, and while is not loaded, render the **Container** (or a loading indicator)
6. Load data in **initState**